# why select query with where clause auto increment Id matched to 'true' returns first row?

Tags: mysql

why select query with where clause auto increment Id  matched to 'true' returns first row?

i.e

```
select * from employee where id = true
```

returns 1st record where id is auto increment value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MySQL casts `true` into 1, so your actual query is the same as:
`select * from employee where id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

**ORDER BY** is your friend. you can use a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
ORDER BY if(id = 77,0,1);
```